# Exception when running Spring Boot app inside of Docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, configserver

I have a problem connecting to the config-server. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I have configured server running in a docker container named "config-server" on port 8888.

```
http://config-server:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
2020-08-10 17:38:35.196 ERROR 11052 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:148) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
```

discovery-server bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-server
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://config-server:8888
      fail-fast: true
      retry:
        max-attempts: 20
```

**EDIT**
config-server Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11.0-jre
ADD ./target/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
EXPOSE 8888
```

docker run -p 8888:8888 --name config-server 3deb982c96fe
Discavery-server is not running in docker. First I want to create its .jar file

Comment: Please show the work. What are the commands used to start both? What are the `Dockerfiles`? What are the log output of both? One guess is that the hostname is not available on default Docker network. You need to create your own network for DNS to resolve container names.

Comment: I think you should try localhost:8888 but to be sure can you show your docker compose or/and docker run command?

Comment: @JAsgarov yes, i connect with localhost, but i think is it not correctly.

Comment: Like i said your server is running on localhost, port 8888 =  http://localhost:8888

Comment: @JAsgarov yes, but shouldn't I refer to it by container name?

Comment: container name is for docker cli commands, now you can execute commands like docker container stop "container-name", not for specifying the dns name. DNS name is necessary for outside calls, from computer that has docker running you can always use localhost

Comment: @JAsgarov ok I understand. I have one more question for you. How do I build a .jar file. When I change the uri address in discavery-server to localhost and build the file, it won't work when I run docker-compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original question already answered in comments, answering the last point here for better formatting:

Jar file will be built in `/target` folder of your application everytime you run `mvn clean install` or `gradle build`. In order to run this in Docker you have to copy the jar file from your `/target` directory to the Docker container inner files, and then run it (`java -jar nameOfYourJar.jar`).

Name of your jar can be defined in maven/gradle settings but to keep your Dockerfile generic I suggest following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0-jre
ARG JAR_FILE=/target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

with `ARG JAR_FILE` you save the path to any jar file (found in target) as `JAR_FILE` variable in docker and then you can copy it to your Docker inner files where it will be stored under the name `app.jar`.

ENTRYPOINT is the command that will be run on container start.

Place the Dockerfile next to the `/target` directory (so in root folder of your app) and run following command in terminal:

`docker build -t springapp . && docker run --rm -d -p 8080:8080 springapp`

Hope this clarifies everything.